# How do I make my python app default to run in rosetta?

Tags: python

I have a Python app that requires some modules that do not have universal binaries. It will not launch natively but runs fine on rosetta2.  The primary purpose of this app is to remove setup issues when sharing an existing python script, so I want to avoid instructing users to go through the Get info > Open in Rosetta step.

I want to send the app in a zip and when the user unzips “Open in Rosetta” would already checked.

Comment: How do you create the Python app? Did you check whether "Open in Rosetta" persists if you set it before zipping? If this fails, can you put the app onto a DMG and use this to distribute your application?

Comment: Given the purpose why do you need binary libraries that purpose sounds like it could use just Python

Comment: @nohillside I am making the app via py2app and checking “Open in Rosetta” does not persist after the zip. To send the app it will need to be zipped, are you assuming the check will persist if I make an app in a DMG then zip it all up?

Comment: @mmmmmm without the binary the app does not run in arm.  It fails with an error specifically stating it is running x86 and needs arm.

Comment: Why can't the binary be written in python? - Agreed not a direct answer to your question Alternatively make a fat binary

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just zipping the application, set the "Open in Rosetta" flag, put the application into a DMG, zip this if necessary and distribute it.